# content is not moving with sliding side menu

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I created a sliding side menu that slides in and out via css.  However, my problem is that even though the side menu slides out of view, the content on the right side doesn't follow it.  It is an angularjs+bootstrap3 app.

Heres an example of the effect I want:
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07H3237

When you click the button with the three horizontal lines on it, it toggles the menu to the side and moves the content with it (leftward).

style.css

```
.sidebart {
    -moz-transition: left .1s;
    -webkit-transition: left .1s;
    -o-transition: left .1s;
    transition: left .1s;
    width: 210px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#2a3542;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.slide-outt {
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
    left: -210px;

}
```

partial.html

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button class="btn btn-default collapse-button" ng-click="click()">Toggle collapse</button>
 <div id="sidebar" class="sidebart" ng-class="{'slide-outt':boolChangeClass}">
<!-- sidebar menu start-->
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
<li>
                                  <a href="#/customer">
                                      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                      <span>Customers</span>
                                  </a>
                              </li>
           <li>
                                  <a href="#/order">
                                      <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
                                      <span>Orders</span>
                                  </a>
                              </li
            </div>
```

controller.js

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.boolChangeClass = !$scope.boolChangeClass;
        //$scope.$apply();
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, did you fix it already?  When I collapse the menu on the left the content on the right appears to expand to fill the area

Comment: "... sliding slide menu that slides ..." Perfect! You may need to reproduce the problem in a fiddle. Use rendered HTML rather than your Angular code. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you talking about the link I posted? Thats just an example of what I want (not what I have achieved yet).  Right now my menu pops to the side but the content on the right side doesn't move lefwtards with it.

Comment: ah okay yeah I was referring to the link thanks for the clarification can you create a plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net showing your problem in action

Answer (score 2):

In the example link you provided there are two important classes at work that you don't mention in your question:

```
.main-content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 240px;
    ...
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.main-content-toggle-left {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The `margin-left: 240px` on `.main-content-wrapper` bumps the main content to the right to accommodate the side of the sidebar. When the sidebar is closed, `.main-content-toggle-left` is applied, therefore reducing the margin via `margin-left: 0;`. This moves the main content back to hug the left side of the screen. Finally, `transition: all .3s ease-in-out;` matches the transition on the sidebar, ensuring that they both move at the same rate.

In your case you are using the `left: -210px` in your `.slide-outt` class instead of margins, presumably with the expectation that if the sidebar moves out of the way the main content will follow. However, since you are using `position: absolute` on your sidebar, [it doesn't push other elements out of the way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), and therefore does not affect the flow of the page when you apply `left: -210px`.

In order for your main content to follow your sidebar you will need to apply a transition to your main content that will move it left at the same rate. The necessary styling is entirely dependant on the current positioning of your main content, but possible common options include changing its `left` value, as with your sidebar, or using margins.

For more information, see the MDN docs on [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), and [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). Note that `left` and `margin` - like many attributes - will produce different results depending on the type of positioning of the element.